# color cells of facet_grid according to cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code clusters the iris data's 4 dimensions:

```
library(SOMbrero)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)

set.seed(42)
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
setwd('C:/Data')

#str(iris)

x_dim = 6
y_dim = 4
Train <- iris

som <- trainSOM(x.data = Train[, 1:4], dimension = c(y_dim, x_dim), maxit = 10000, scaling = "unitvar", radius.type = "letremy")

superClass <- superClass(som, k = 3)
summary(superClass)

Train$Cluster = superClass$cluster[superClass$som$clustering]
Train$Node = superClass$som$clustering
Train$X = som$parameters$the.grid$coord[superClass$som$clustering, 1]
Train$Y = som$parameters$the.grid$coord[superClass$som$clustering, 2]

bp <- ggplot(Train, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_grid(Y ~ X)
bp
```

The last bit depict the grid and on aspect of it: Sepal.Length. I would like to change the background color of each grid cell according to the cluster membership defined by column Cluster, e.g.:

```
Cluster = 1 => red  
Cluster = 2 => blue
Cluster = 3 => black
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

PS:

```
bp <- ggplot(Train, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = factor(Cluster))) +
    geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.01) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_grid(Y ~ X)
bp
```

Comment: You can use `geom_ribbon` to color background, or you could perhaps [color strips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440069/ggplot2-facet-wrap-strip-color-based-on-variable-in-data-set)?

Comment: @zx8754 - I cam across this but I could not understand it - hence my post. How would I use this for my exact problem?

Comment: @cs0815 add this before boxplot line: `geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf)` and add `fill = factor(Cluster)` to ggplot aes.