# How to specify different background colors for each facet label in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

A plot will be made from these data:

```
library(ggplot2)  
mtcars %>%
    gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
    theme_bw()
```

How can I change the gray color of the titles of the panels
for instance

- panels of am and hp   green
- panels of gear drat disp   red
- panels  of vs wt   blue
- panels cyl qsec carb black

add a legend

- green  = area
- red =  bat
- blue = vege
- black = indus

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440069/ggplot2-facet-wrap-strip-color-based-on-variable-in-data-set).

Comment: It looks like this might be the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589891/17852787

Comment: @René The link that you have provided leads to the same post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems the way to answer OP's question is still going to be quite hacky.

If you're not into [gtable hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440069/ggplot2-facet-wrap-strip-color-based-on-variable-in-data-set) like those referenced... here's another exceptionally hacky way to do this.  Enjoy the strange ride.

TL;DR - The idea here is to use a rect geom *outside of the plot area* to draw each facet label box color

Here's the basic plot below.  OP wanted to (1) change the gray color behind the facet labels (called the "strip" labels) to a specific color depending on the facet label, then (2) add a legend.

First of all, I just referenced the gathered dataframe as `df`, so the plot code looks like this now:

```
df <- mtcars %>% gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value")

ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### How to recolor each facet label?

As referenced in the other answers, it's pretty simple to change all the facet label colors at once (and facet label text) via the `theme()` elements `strip.background` and `strip.text`:

```
plot + theme(
  strip.background = element_rect(fill="blue"), 
  strip.text=element_text(color="white"))
```

[image]

Of course, we can't do that for all facet labels, because `strip.background` and `element_rect()` cannot be sent a vector or have mapping applied to the aesthetics.

The idea here is that we use something that *can* have aesthetics mapped to data (and therefore change according to the data) - use a geom.  In this case, I'm going to use `geom_rect()` to draw a rectangle in each facet, then color that rect based upon the criteria OP states in their question.  Moreover, using `geom_rect()` in this way also *creates a legend automatically for us*, since we are going to use mapping and `aes()` to specify the color.  All we need to do is allow `ggplot2` to draw layers outside the plot area, use a bit of manual fine-tuning to get the placement correct, and it works!

#### The Hack

First, a separate dataset is created containing a column called `var` that contains all facet names.  Then `var_color` specifies the names OP gave for each facet.  We specify color using a `scale_fill_manual()` function.  Finally, it's important to use `coord_cartesian()` carefully here.  We need this function for two reasons:

1. Cut the panel area in the plot to only contain the *points*.  If we did not specify the y limit, the panel would automatically resize to accomodate the rect geom.
2. Turn clipping off.  This allows layers drawn outside the panel to be seen.

We then need to turn `strip.background` to transparent (so we can see the color of the box), and we're good to go.  Hopefully you can follow along below.

I'm representing all the code below for extra clarity:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# dataset for plotting
df <- mtcars %>% gather(-mpg, key = "var", value = "value")

# dataset for facet label colors
hacky_df <- data.frame(
  var = c("am", "carb", "cyl", "disp", "drat", "gear", "hp", "qsec", "vs", "wt"),
  var_color = c("area", "indus", "indus", "bat", "bat", "bat", "area", "indus", "vege", "vege")
)

# plot code
plot_new <-
  ggplot(df) +    # don't specify x and y here.  Otherwise geom_rect will complain.
  geom_rect(
    data=hacky_df,
    aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf,
        ymin=36, ymax=42,     # totally defined by trial-and-error
        fill=var_color, alpha=0.4)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) +     
  coord_cartesian(clip="off", ylim=c(10, 35)) +
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("area" = "green", "bat" = "red", "vege" = "blue", "indus" = "black")) +
  
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA),
    strip.text = element_text(face="bold")
  )

plot_new
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the only problem of this approach is when y axis is totally different between the variables, so we can not do aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf,
        ymin=36, ymax=42.  Do you know how to assign the max of each variable?

Comment: It's a bit of work, but totally doable.  Instead of defining a value for `ymin` and `ymax` within `aes()` you would define those values within `hacky_df` as new columns and then map the column.  Ex.: add `bottom = c(...),` and `top = c(...)` to `hacky_df`, then replace `ymin=36` with `ymin=bottom` and `ymax=42` with `ymax=top`.

Comment: Thanks and we need ylim? how to cope with it?

Comment: Yes, you will need to keep the `ylim(...)` part within `coord_cartesian()`.  Otherwise, the scale will automatically adjust to keep the rectangles inside the dimension of the plot.  You can just set the dimensions based on the data: ex. `ylim = c(max(mtcars$mpg), min(mtcars$mpg))`

Comment: Thanks but this will not be the max and min for each variable. it will be min and max for all varaibles.

Comment: Correct.  You'll have to adjust the positions of `ymin=` and `ymax=` for the individual facets by mapping in `hacky_df` like I reference above if the y axis scales are different and your actual data has variation.  The question posted has the y scale identical for all, so it was not clear to me your data has this variation.  I see now setting `ylim()` universally is going to be a problem there.

Comment: Your option might be `patchwork` or `grid.arrange()` or `cowplot()` with individual plots or a list of plots, then you can control each individually.

Comment: Neat @chemdork123, even easier than [the nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589891/10852113) by baptiste.